# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' but it's installed?

Tags: python, pycharm

I used the command `pip install requests` in CMD and successfully installed the requests module, but when I try and import it to my file in PyCharm it throws

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I saw a couple other posts about this issue but did not find a working solution.

As a side note I have successfully run this code in my Python IDLE so I presume this is not a code issue, and just an issue with my PyCharm settings.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danie/PycharmProjects/Web_Scraping_Project/Web_Scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate the virtual environment.

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install requests
```

Or you can add the library, from the PyCharm GUI.
There is a "+" on the [edit interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#modify_interpreter) in settings in the, click on it and search for the `requests` library.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if your project is using a virtualenv python environment. The pip install you did is probably on your system wide python installation.

You can install packages by activating your virutalenv (source path/to/venv/bin/activate) and using pip as usual, installing packages using the PyCharm interface (you can see a litte "+" button in your screenshot) or just by using the terminal in PyCharm (this should activate the virtualenv automatically).